# Log in with RememberMe token in tests

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Im trying to login with a `RememberMe token`, so I can test that my controller does what it needs to do, when you are not fully logged in.

As I have my users as `in_memory` in my security test configuration, the following does not work, and gives me a exception that the `User` object is not part of my security. So how should I create my `RememberMeToken` object?

With the `UsernamePasswordToken` its possible to just pass a string as user, but not with the `RememberMeToken`

```
protected function logInWithToken($role = 'ROLE_USER'): void
    {
        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewallName = 'main';
        $firewallContext = 'main';

            $token = new RememberMeToken(
                new User($role),
                $firewallName,
                'secret'
            );

        $session->set('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
```